# Stuck on some angular arithmetic

Tags: java, android, wolfram-mathematica, trigonometry, angle

Hallo,

I'm having trouble writing a function:

```
float turnToRequestedHeading(float initialHeading, float requiredHeading, float turnRate)
```

I keep thinking there must be a clever way to do it, but it escapes me.

All values are in Radians, Headings between -PI and +PI, and turnRate between -0.5 and +0.5.

If the requiredHeading is less than the turnRate away from the initialHeading then it should return requiredHeading

Otherwise it should return initialHeading + or - turnRate, whichever gets closer to the requiredHeading.

Any ideas? I get stuck when the headings are either side of straight down, e.g. -3 and +3.

UPDATE: Here is some test code and test data (see my answer for my code below):

```
private void turnToRequestedHeadingTest(float initialHeading, float requiredHeading, float turnRate, float expectedResult) {
    if (Math.round(turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading*PIf/180, requiredHeading*PIf/180, turnRate*PIf/180)*180/PIf) != expectedResult) {
        /*DEBUG*/Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "test(initial="+initialHeading+", required="+requiredHeading+", rate="+turnRate+") Expected "+expectedResult+", Returns "+(Math.round(turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading*PIf/180, requiredHeading*PIf/180, turnRate*PIf/180)*180/PIf)));
    }
}

    /*DEBUG*/Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading tests:");
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(   0,   0,  0,   0);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(   0,   0, 25,   0);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  10,  15, 25,  15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  20,  55, 25,  45);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  85,  95, 25,  95);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 150,-170, 25, 175);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 170, 177, 25, 177);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 170,-175, 25,-175);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 175,-100, 25,-160);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 175,   0, 25, 150);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 180,   0, 25, 155);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-170,-100, 25,-145);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-100, -80, 25, -80);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -30, -15, 25, -15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -30,  15, 25,  -5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -20,  -5, 25,  -5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -20,   5, 25,   5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -20,  15, 25,   5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  10, 180, 25,  35);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  10,-160, 25, -15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 170,   0, 25, 145);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 170, -15, 25,-165);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-170,   5, 25,-145);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -10, 160, 25,  15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -10,-150, 25, -35);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  10,-170, 25, -15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(   0, 180, 25,  25);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -10, -15, 25, -15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -20, -55, 25, -45);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -85, -95, 25, -95);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-150, 170, 25,-175);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-170,-177, 25,-177);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-170, 175, 25, 175);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-175, 100, 25, 160);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-175,   0, 25,-150);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 170, 100, 25, 145);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 100,  80, 25,  80);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  30,  15, 25,  15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  30, -15, 25,   5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  20,   5, 25,   5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  20,  -5, 25,  -5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  20, -15, 25,  -5);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -10,-180, 25, -35);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -10, 160, 25,  15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-170,   0, 25,-145);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-170,  15, 25, 165);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 170,  -5, 25, 145);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  10,-160, 25, -15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  10, 150, 25,  35);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -10, 170, 25,  15);
    // More tests
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(   0,  15, 25,  15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(   0,  60, 25,  25);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(   0, -15, 25, -15);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(   0, -60, 25, -25);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 180, 165, 25, 165);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 180, 100, 25, 155);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 180,-165, 25,-165);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 180,-100, 25,-155);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-180, 165, 25, 165);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-180, 100, 25, 155);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-180,-165, 25,-165);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-180,-100, 25,-155);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  25,   0, 25,   0);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(  25, -25, 25,   0);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -25,   0, 25,   0);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( -25,  25, 25,   0);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 155, 180, 25, 180);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 155,-155, 25, 180);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-155, 180, 25,-180);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-155, 155, 25,-180);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest( 155,-180, 25,-180);
    turnToRequestedHeadingTest(-155,-180, 25,-180);
```

I think my test data covers all cases now...

-Frink

Comment: It still gets the test(initial=155.0, required=-180.0, rate=25.0) Expected -180.0, Returns 180 'wrong' but that's probably just a rounding error

Comment: Every couple of years I solve this problem. Again. And again. It's so annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I have come up with which satisfies my test data and seems to behave properly in my code. Still looks over-complex to me though...

```
// return the new heading based on the required heading and turn rate
private float turnToRequestedHeading(float initialHeading, float requiredHeading, float turnRate) {
    //DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Started");
    float resultantHeading;
    int   direction = 1;            // clockwise, set anti-clockwise (-1) later if required
    if ((Math.signum(initialHeading) == Math.signum(requiredHeading)) || (Math.signum(initialHeading) == 0) || (Math.signum(requiredHeading) == 0)) {
        // both headings are on the same side of 0 so turn will not pass through the  +/- Pi discontinuity
        if (Math.max(Math.abs(requiredHeading) - Math.abs(initialHeading), Math.abs(initialHeading) - Math.abs(requiredHeading)) < turnRate) {
            // angle to be updated is less than turn rate
            resultantHeading= requiredHeading;
            /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path1");
        } else {
            // angle to be updated is greater than turn rate
            if (initialHeading < requiredHeading) {
                // turn clockwise
                resultantHeading = initialHeading + turnRate;
                /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path2");
            } else {
                // turn anti-clockwise
                resultantHeading = initialHeading - turnRate;
                /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path3");
            }
        }
    } else {
        // headings are on different sides of 0 so turn may pass through the +/- Pi discontinuity
        if (Math.abs(initialHeading) + Math.abs(requiredHeading) < turnRate) {
            // angle to be updated is less than turn rate (around 0)
            resultantHeading= requiredHeading;
            /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path4");
        } else if ((180 - Math.abs(initialHeading)) + (180 - Math.abs(requiredHeading)) < turnRate) {
            // angle to be updated is less than turn rate (around +/- Pi)
            resultantHeading= requiredHeading;
            /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path5");
        } else {
            // angle to be updated is greater than turn rate so calculate direction (previously assumed to be 1)
            if (initialHeading < 0) {
                if (requiredHeading > PIf + initialHeading) direction = -1;
            } else {
                if (requiredHeading > -PIf + initialHeading) direction = -1;
            }
            if ((direction == 1) && (initialHeading > PIf - turnRate)) {
                // angle includes the +/- Pi discontinuity, clockwise
                resultantHeading = -TWO_PIf + turnRate + initialHeading;
                /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path6 snap="+(resultantHeading > requiredHeading));
                if (resultantHeading > requiredHeading) resultantHeading = requiredHeading;
            } else if ((direction == -1) && (initialHeading < -PIf + turnRate)) {
                // angle includes the +/- Pi discontinuity, anti-clockwise
                resultantHeading = TWO_PIf - turnRate + initialHeading;
                /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path7 snap="+(resultantHeading < requiredHeading));
                if (resultantHeading < requiredHeading) resultantHeading = requiredHeading;
            } else {
                // angle does not includes the +/- Pi discontinuity
                resultantHeading = initialHeading + direction * turnRate;
                /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading(initialHeading="+initialHeading+", requiredHeading="+requiredHeading+", turnRate="+turnRate+"): Path8 direction="+direction);
            }
        }
    }
    // ensure -PI <= result <= PI
    if (resultantHeading < -PIf) resultantHeading = resultantHeading + TWO_PIf; 
    if (resultantHeading >= PIf)  resultantHeading = resultantHeading - TWO_PIf; 
    //DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "turnToRequestedHeading: Returning "+resultantHeading);
    return resultantHeading;
}
```

Feel free to point out any errors! (with example values please!)

-Frink

Answer (score 2):

If this is a function that gets called often I would stay away from modular division because it is a relatively expensive operation. In your case, the turns can only ever exceed Pi or -Pi by less than one revolution so we can use adding or subtracting Pi from the value to correct for this mistake which is a cheaper option performance wise.

```
//helper function to determine the distance, in radians, between two headings
float AngularDist(float heading1, float heading2) //assumes all headings are between -Pi and Pi
{
   if(heading1*heading2>0.0) //this checks if they have the same sign. If so result will be positive
   {
      return(abs(heading1-heading2));
   }
   else //If the headings don't have the same sign we need to do some extra math to check whether it is shorter to turn clockwise or counterclockwise to reach other angle
   {
      float clockwise=abs(heading1)+abs(heading2);
      float counterclockwise=2.0*Pi-clockwise;
      if(clockwise<counterclockwise)
         return(clockwise);
      else
         return(counterclockwise);
   }
}

float turnToRequestedHeading(float initialHeading, float requiredHeading, float turnRate)
    {
     if((AngularDist(initialHeading,requiredHeading)/turnRate<1.0) //if the turn is too small return required
    {
       return(requiredHeading)
    }
    else
    {
       float positiveTurn=initialHeading+turnRate
       //need to check if variable is greater than Pi
       if(positiveTurn>Pi)
          positiveTurn-=Pi;
       float negativeTurn=initialHeading-turnRate
       //need to check if we variable is less than -Pi
       if(negativeTurn<-Pi)
          negativeTurn+=Pi;

       if(AngularDist(negativeTurn,requiredHeading)<AngularDist(positiveTurn,requiredHeading))
          return(negativeTurn);
       else
          return(positiveTurn);

    }

}
```

EDIT
  Saw that my original code to check if the new heading was less than one turn rate away incorrectly used absolute value and corrected it.
EDIT 2: commenter is right that the case for handling wrapping from a positive to negative number was incorrect. Fixed it by adding a helper function that just calculates distance. I imagine that this will be inlined by the compiler, but it might be worth checking the disassembly to make sure that it is.

Comment: Cheers. I'll have to think about using your alternative to % as other parts of my code may produce > Pi values. I may have to check every time

Comment: @Samsdram I'm not sure that the above code is correct.  When I plug values of -3, 2.5 and 0.5 in for `initialHeading`, `requiredHeading` and `turnRate` respectively, I think I should get back a value of 2.7831... however the above returns a value of 2.5.

Comment: I ran your code against my tests and there were errors, e.g. test(initial=175.0, required=-100.0, rate=25.0) Expected -160.0, Returns 150. I told you it was harder than it looks!

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave the question says all headings will be in Radians between -pi and pi. So the code was written based on that. That inputs in degrees don't give the expected answer isn't surprising.

Comment: @Samsdram, Yeah, my test code uses degrees tho as it was easier for me to understand. It (hopefully) converts everything to Radians and back again (although I haven't specifically tested that)

Answer (score 1):

Use the % operator against 2pi. So you might have something like this as part of your method:

```
if ( (requiredHeading-initialHeading) % ( 2.0*Math.PI) < turnRate )
    return requiredHeading;
```

You may need to put in some explicit casts to float or double.

Comment: Cheers Jems, I'm not sure if I need 2.0*Math.PI or just Math.PI as % may allow -ve values, but I'm not going to investigate further as Samsdram reckons it's inefficient for my needs